# Show UIView/UIImage/UITextView while function is running

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimage, activity-indicator

### OBJECTIVE

I am trying to display a UIView, UIImage, and UITextView when a function is running in order to let a user know it is processing (similar to an Activity Indicator, but more customized).

### PROBLEM

When the code below is processing, the UIView, UIImage, and UITextView don't display until a moment before the function **finishes** running (instead of **showing** as soon the function **starts** running and **hiding** when the function **finishes**).

### CURRENT APPROACH:

I have created a UIView (loadingView) which contains and image (loadingIcon) and a textView (loadingText) explaining to the user that the app is processing.

I have also created a function called isLoading, which displays or hides all 3, rather than repeating these lines multiple times.  I have tested setting isLoading to true and false in the viewDidLoad to make sure that it is working properly.

```
@IBOutlet weak var loadingView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var loadingIcon: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var loadingText: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    isLoading(false)
}


func isLoading(_ loadStatus: Bool) {
    if loadStatus == true {
        loadingView.isHidden = false
        loadingIcon.isHidden = false
        loadingText.isHidden = false
    } else {
        loadingView.isHidden = true
        loadingIcon.isHidden = true
        loadingText.isHidden = true
    }
}

@IBAction func sendButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    isLoading(true)

    ... //process information, which takes some time

    isLoading(false)
}
```

Any help, suggestions, or thoughts are immensely appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Use completion handler to hide your Views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running the process on the main queue so your UI appears to hang until it is finished. You need to process the information in the background. A common pattern you might use would be:

```
@IBAction func sendButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    isLoading(true)

    // Do the processing in the background    
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        ... //process information, which takes some time

        // And update the UI on the main queue
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            isLoading(false)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @rmaddy!

Comment: As a helpful tip to any others that have this similar question, I was calling a segue programmatically at the end of the "//process information, which takes some time" section above.  By moving this call to the main thread ("DispatchQueue.main.asyc{ ... }") worked great!